# Gorilla mux REST api gives 405 error on using POST with double slash but still works on using GET

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

My code looks like this

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Methods("POST").Path("/api1").Handler(...)
r.Methods("GET").Path("/api2").Handler(...)
```

When I call `GET http://localhost/api1`, `GET http://localhost//api1`, `POST http://localhost/api2`, they work normally. But I call `POST http://localhost//api2`, it returns error "405-Method Not Allowed".

This is my full code

Firstly, I create my default router

```
func NewDefaultRouter(config RouterConfig) *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    writerMW := http_middleware.NewResponseWriterMiddleware()
    loggingMW := http_middleware.NewLoggingMiddleware(config.Logger)
    metricMW := http_middleware.NewMetricsMiddleware(config.PathMapper)

    router.Use(writerMW)
    router.Use(loggingMW)
    router.Use(metricMW)
}
```

After that, I add handler for each http endpoints

```
    r.Methods("GET").Path("/user/{userID:[0-9]+}").Handler(kithttp.NewServer(
        endpoints.GetUser,
        decode.GetUserRequest,
        pkghttp.EncodeResponse,
        options...,
    ))

    r.Methods("POST").Path("/user").Handler(kithttp.NewServer(
        endpoints.PostUser,
        decode.PostUserRequest,
        pkghttp.EncodeResponse,
        options...,
    ))
```

Comment: Can you share more code? are you handling `r` before starting your server? Also your router is `router` but you are registering your handlers on `r`

Comment: oh, sorry, ```router``` is ```r```

Comment: I added my code into the question

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to find out why you are getting a Method Not Allowed response. The following code (on the lines what what you have shared) should work as expected

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Methods("GET").Path("/user/{userID:[0-9]+}").HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("GET Call")
    })
    r.Methods("POST").Path("/user").HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("POST Call")
    })

    http.Handle("/", r)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":3030", nil))
}
```

```
curl -i  http://localhost:3030/user/123123
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 05:44:17 GMT
Content-Length: 0

curl -i -XPOST  http://localhost:3030/user
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 05:44:23 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: if you call ```curl -i -XPOST  http://localhost:3030//user```, you will get error. Maybe a bug of gorilla, I found that gorilla change the path to ```/user``` but method become GET, not still POST